# cordova-plugin-appavailability is not detecting facebook app

Tags: facebook, cordova, cordova-plugins, uri-scheme

I am using the AppAvailability cordova plugin to check if the facebook app is installed on a device from my own app.

In order to test its working, I have the facebook app installed on my iOS device. the appAvailability.check() should therefore execute the success function however it is executing the error callback function instead. Can you help? (I am unable to post the issue on [the github page](https://github.com/ohh2ahh/AppAvailability) as issues are closed.)

I have this in the config.xml

```
<plugin name="cordova-plugin-appavailability" spec="0.4.2" source="npm" />
```

and in my javascript i have the following:

```
var scheme = "fb://";
appAvailability.check(
      scheme,       // URI Scheme or Package Name 
      function() {  // Success callback 
            alert(scheme + ' is available :)');
      },
      function() {  // Error callback 
             //this is being executed even when the fb app IS installed.
            alert(scheme + ' is not available :(');
      }
);
```

Comment: I seem to have bumped into the same problem. Did you ever find a solution for this?

Comment: @PriiduNeemre Sorry but I never found a solution for this... I gave up on the plugin shortly after.

Answer (score 1):

Sample I'm showing is for ios.  Make sure you edit the plist (platforms/ios/appname/appname-Info.plist) file for your app and add facebook.

```
<key>LSApplicationQueriesSchemes</key>
<array>
    <string>facebook</string>
</array>
```

Comment: This had to be `<string>fb</string>` for me on iOS11.

Answer (score 0):

In your androidmanifest.xml file just add the below code on above or below   tag.

```
<queries>
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp" />
    <package android:name="com.whatsapp.w4b" />
</queries>
```